# what's the best way to find the file in nested folders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I found some legacy code where a factory load one file from sub-tree directory.

```
var name = 'file.js'
try {
  return require('folder/foo/' + name)
} catch (e) {
  try {
    return require('folder/foo/bar/' + name)
  } catch (ee) {
    return null
  }
}
```

How can I avoid the nested try/catch blocks for each folder level?
I tried this.

```
const name = 'file.js'
const pathList = ['folder/foo/', 'folder/foo/bar/']
return pathList.map(path => {
        const file = `${path}${name}`
        try {
            return require(file).default
        } catch (exception) {
            return null
        }
    })
```

But this changes the behaviour. If the file is not found on first level it returns null instead of taking the next level. It doesn't help if I change the order at the pathList declaration.

Is there a better way in a React app environment? I cannot use FS from node.js.

Comment: `.map(...).find(Boolean)`?

Comment: are you not missing a `/` in the expression `${path}${name}`, between path and name?

Comment: @Chris thanks, I updated the examples.

Comment: @RonnySpringer, you mean it returns `pathList` as null or just the item whose path failed to resolve? Let's say `folder/foo/file.js` doesn't exist but `folder/foo/bar/file.js` does, what's the expected return value?

Comment: @Chris this is the right example. The return value is null. The first run is catched because the file is not inside `folder/foo`. How can I run the secound iteration?